# Error of "Error in sourceCpp("xx.cpp") : Error 1 occurred building shared library."

Tags: r, rcpp

I'd like to do some research based on a paper whose codes are: https://github.com/Xiaolu-Zhu/LongitudinalClustering.

In the "sample.R" script, there is such a command

```
sourceCpp("admmmcp_code.cpp");
```

And it goes wrong with the error

```
Error in sourceCpp("admmmcp_code.cpp") : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

I have checked about the Rtools with

```
writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

and

```
Sys.which("make")
```

So I believe I have installed the Rtools correctly on my Windows.

Comment: You can do one better and actually test. Try `Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")`.  Unless you see four returned your setup is not right.  That only tests compilation without additional depencies; the code you try above may have extra requirements.

Comment: I have tried ` Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")` and it returned 4. I also tried the repo on Rstudio cloud. So I think there is no error with the Rtools path. Thank you all the same! @Dirk Eddelbuettel

Comment: So I guess the issue is then between you and that other repo.  Do you have RcppArmadillo installed? That code seems to require it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we have established that you have a working Rtools setup, make sure you have *required* R packages. I do, and it works here:

```
R> download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xiaolu-Zhu/LongitudinalClustering/master/admmmcp_code.cpp", "/tmp/admmmcp_code.cpp")
trying URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Xiaolu-Zhu/LongitudinalClustering/master/admmmcp_code.cpp'
Content type 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' length 8118 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 8118 bytes

R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/admmmcp_code.cpp")
R> ls()
 [1] "prclust_admm"     "prox_L2"         
 [3] "residual_dual"    "residual_primal" 
 [5] "tolerance_dual"   "tolerance_primal"
 [7] "update_B"         "update_B_ini"    
 [9] "update_Lambda"    "update_V"        
R>
```

So in particular, make sure you have `RcppArmadillo` installed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have pasted the complete error here. I have solved the error now——There is `#include <Rcpp>` in the cpp file. After I deleted it, it worked.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad worked. Note that I did not have to remove the line.  Now, for the benefit of StackOverflow, it is common for someone like you who _asks_ a question to _accept the answer_ when it is suitable (click on the "tick" mark you as asker see) and/or to also _upvote_ the answer (clock on the up-ward triangle).  Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow :)